# Modifying node submission form labels in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I've created a new node type that is identical to a page called "foo", except there is an extra text field, "bar".

When I want to add a new "foo" form as a user, the label for this field "bar" appears above the input box. I would not like it to be present.

I couldn't find any way to remove it in the admin section, and if that's not the case, I tried writing a simple module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "foo_node_form") {
        unset($form['bar']['#title']);
    }
}
```

My intention is that this will remove the input field's label but alas, no joy. Any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://drupal.org/node/601646...

Try

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "foo_node_form") {
        unset($form['bar']['value']['#title']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas, no joy with that either. I'm wondering if it might be the order in which Drupal calls form_alter?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to hide a label, then why not use CSS? Apply a `display: none;` on the label. You would use hook_form_alter for a bit more advanced work, such as removing form items entirely or adding custom submit handlers.